# FFMPEG terrible conversion quality when using -sameq (same quantizer as source) flag

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert .flv videos to .ogg format. After experimenting for a while, the ogg is always produced as very low quality. Even when I use the `-sameq` flag which uses the same quantizer as the input file, the quality is substantially worse.

Since I am pretty new with ffmpeg, does anyone know some good options to convert video files with maximum quality?

Comment: I don't know if it's the source of the behavior you're seeing, but double-check the playback software you're using.  I've known past versions of VLC to give noticeably different results depending on the container format used.  Since ogg isn't exactly the most widely-used format, maybe you're running into something similar.

Comment: `-sameq` is not same quality - http://superuser.com/a/478550/60507

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I remember -sameq can mimic the quality to a certain level with the limitation of buffsize. Means either you need put some extra settings in use which I think mostly concerns -buffsize, buffer related settings etc.. (But i may be wrong i'm not using ffmpeg for a year.)

Or use the qscale tag if you need the best, but i need to warn you the size of the output will 3 or 4 times bigger differentiating on video. Usage is `-qscale [x]` where [x] (without brackets) is the quality value of output, lower is better. If you put `-qscale 0` it means the best. Also you may want to use `-ar` (audio frequency) and `-ab` (audio bitrate: 192k is enough for HD, 128k is the most common) for better audio quality.

Example usage of -qscale -ar -ab tags:

```
-i a1.wmv -qscale 0 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -y aOut.wmv
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that at least in FFMpeg 0.6, `-qscale` takes a value between 1 ("excellent quality") and 255 ("worst quality"), so if anyone wants to achieve the same effect as described above, `-qscale 1` is what you want. Don't know if this has changed, but [here's the note](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Tips) about the current state of affairs in the FFMpeg documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should not convert any audio files using `-sameq`... The best command line to convert audio files is to use variable bitrates which is the `-qscale:a 1` command. It will form a transparent sounds quality which is best for most audiophiles out there... As much as possible, don't replace `1` into `0` because the other sounds will get muffled. And muffled sound is what you hear on every bad audio files...

Comment: Additionally, you may also want to change your sample format which s32, s24, and s16 command. Example command line here is "-sample_fmt s32"